# How do I program an INTEL GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel

I am quite new in the world of GPU Computing. So I would really like someone to explain me the very basics. I have to Intel chipsets with the following GPUs:

- GMA4500
- HD graphics

I am interested in running algebraic and bitwise functions with huge data sets, like transpose of an array or bitwise shift of the lines of an array, in a GPU. The goal is of course to gain more performance.

My main question is how can I program such on GPUs? In the past I have used CUDA to program on nVIDIA video card. I understand from previous topics that I can't use CUDA for an INTEL GPUs. Thanks in advance!!

**Update 1**

I found out that Intel supports OpenCL for HD graphics. More precisely the Intel SDK for OpenCL applications provides a comprehensive development environment for OpenCL application on Intel® platforms including compatible drivers, code samples, development tools, such as the code builder, optimization guide, and support for optimization tools.

The SDK supports OpenCL 1.2 on 3rd and 4th generation Intel® Core™ processors with Intel® HD Graphics and Intel® Iris™ Graphics Family, Intel® Atom™ Processors with Intel HD Graphics, Intel® Xeon® processors, and Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessors.

Comment: OpenCL might be your search word.

Comment: Maybe there are some opencl beta drivers floating around so that you can use but very low probability, making a GL wrapper can be good. Such as lighting instead of multiplication and blending instead of adding.

Answer (score 9):

[OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is the standard, cross-vendor API for GPGPU programming, roughly analogous to nVidia's proprietary CUDA.

Comment: /agree , CUDA doesn't run on non-NVIDIA GPUs and I don't know AMP's status (it might not even support integrated chipsets)

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units HD graphics and GMA4500 do not support openCL

Comment: Hmm, looks like that GPU was released in 2008, about a year before the first version of OpenCL.  If it supports OpenGL fragment shaders, you can do some limited computational work with those, but  you may just need to get a newer GPU.  The 4500 wasn't designed to support anything but graphics.